# HTML Canvas: Replace the Shapes with Numbers (ctx)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

So I have the following HTML/JS Canvas Wave Animation using shapes:

https://codepen.io/baidoc/pen/yLBgppw

I'm trying to replace the round shapes through binary code. In the end, it'll look like a wave of binary code (01010101) instead of a wave of shapes.

What's the best approach to achieve this? Draw custom SVGs or through CTX FillText?

```
function drawParticle(particle, canvas, ctx) {
  canvas = document.getElementById('binary-canvas');
  const vh = canvas.height / 100;

  ctx.fillStyle = particle.colour;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(
    particle.x * canvas.width,
    particle.y * vh + (canvas.height / 2),
    particle.diameter * vh,
    particle.diameter * vh,
    0,
    0,
    2 * Math.PI
  );
  ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: If you just want to draw simple text characters, I'd stick with `ctx.fillText()` as being the simplest approach. SVG does have a couple of advanced features, such as drawing text along a [`<textPath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath), but I doubt you need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best here will probably be to use [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) to render your texts.

Of course you could use [`fillText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText), but it's a really slow method, so the less you call it, the better your perf will be, and for a particle system, perf matters.

So first, prepare two canvases, one with the "0" and the other with the "1" drawn on it.
Then, when you initialize your particles, you just have to store which of these canvases they'll refer to.
Finally, simply call `ctx.drawImage` with the particle's stored canvas, its coords and its size:

```js
// returns a new <canvas> with given character drawn on it
// can be used directly with drawImage
function makeCharacterCanvas( txt ) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width =  canvas.height = 50;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.font = "50px monospace";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseLine = "bottom";
  ctx.fillText(txt, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
  return canvas;
}
const chars = [makeCharacterCanvas('0'), makeCharacterCanvas('1')];

// OP's code below

// modified version of random-normal
function normalPool(o){var r=0;do{var a=Math.round(normal({mean:o.mean,dev:o.dev}));if(a<o.pool.length&&a>=0)return o.pool[a];r++}while(r<100)}function randomNormal(o){if(o=Object.assign({mean:0,dev:1,pool:[]},o),Array.isArray(o.pool)&&o.pool.length>0)return normalPool(o);var r,a,n,e,l=o.mean,t=o.dev;do{r=(a=2*Math.random()-1)*a+(n=2*Math.random()-1)*n}while(r>=1);return e=a*Math.sqrt(-2*Math.log(r)/r),t*e+l}

const NUM_PARTICLES = 500;
const PARTICLE_SIZE = 1.5; // View heights
const SPEED = 30000; // Milliseconds

let particles = [];

function rand(low, high) {
  return Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
}

function createParticle(canvas) {
  return {
    x: -2,
    y: -2,
    diameter: Math.max(0, randomNormal({ mean: PARTICLE_SIZE, dev: PARTICLE_SIZE / 2 })),
    duration: randomNormal({ mean: SPEED, dev: SPEED * 0.1 }),
    amplitude: randomNormal({ mean: 16, dev: 2 }),
    offsetY: randomNormal({ mean: 0, dev: 10 }),
    arc: Math.PI * 2,
    startTime: performance.now() - rand(0, SPEED),
// [edit] 
    // store which character this particle will hold
    char: chars[+(Math.random() > .5)],
    // We lost colour, but still have opacity
    opacity: rand(0, 1)
  }
}

function moveParticle(particle, canvas, time) {
  const progress = ((time - particle.startTime) % particle.duration) / particle.duration;
  return {
    ...particle,
    x: progress,
    y: ((Math.sin(progress * particle.arc) * particle.amplitude) + particle.offsetY),
  };
}

function drawParticle(particle, canvas, ctx) {
  canvas = document.getElementById('binary-canvas');
  const vh = canvas.height / 100;
// [edit]
  // set opacity
  ctx.globalAlpha = particle.opacity;
  // draw the corresponding <canvas>
  ctx.drawImage(
    particle.char,
    particle.x * canvas.width,
    particle.y * vh + (canvas.height / 2),
    particle.diameter * vh * 2,
    particle.diameter * vh * 2
  )
}

function draw(time, canvas, ctx) {
  // Move particles
  particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
    particles[index] = moveParticle(particle, canvas, time);
  })

  // Clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Draw the particles
  particles.forEach((particle) => {
    drawParticle(particle, canvas, ctx);
  })

  // Schedule next frame
  requestAnimationFrame((time) => draw(time, canvas, ctx));
}

function initializeCanvas() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('binary-canvas');
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  })

  return [canvas, ctx];
}

function startAnimation() {
  const [canvas, ctx] = initializeCanvas();

  // Create a bunch of particles
  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
    particles.push(createParticle(canvas));
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame((time) => draw(time, canvas, ctx));
};

// Start animation when document is loaded
(function () {
  if (document.readystate !== 'loading') {
    startAnimation();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      startAnimation();
    })
  }
}());
```

```css
html, body {
  background:#111830;
  background-image: url("https://cl.profi-homepage.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/bg_nur_highlight-1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 0;
}

#binary-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="binary-canvas"></canvas>
```

One draw back is that you loose a bit of the randomness in the colors, but given the ones in your original snippet, I'll assume opacity is enough.

Comment: thank you! If I'd want an additional color (2 colors) to numbers (for example, 0 red and 1 blue), what'd be the best way to do it?

Comment: In `makeCharacterCanvas` you can add a new param with `txt`, and use it in `ctx.fillStyle = ...` so for instance `function makeCharacterCanvas( txt, color ) { ` (...) `ctx.fillStyle = color;` (...). Or since you only have two choices and want each text to have one color, you can even just set `ctx.fillStyle = txt === "0" ? "white" : " blue";`

Comment: @Kaaido, out of curiosity, the performance on Firefox is different than on Chrome. It's laggy on Firefox and smoother on Chrome, the animation. Is this a known issue?